# Variadic template constructor and copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, variadic-templates

I don't understand why the compiler chooses the copy constructor of my `Production` class and has no other candidate functions.
I made a minimal example to demonstrate the error:

```
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>
#include <iostream>

struct DummyProduction {
};

struct Dep {
};

struct Pro {
};

class ModuleBase {
};

template<typename Production = DummyProduction>
class Provider {
public:
  template<typename... Dependencies>
  Provider(ModuleBase& module, Dependencies... args)
  {
    std::cout << "Provider called!" << std::endl;
  }
  Provider(const Provider&) = delete;
};

class TargetController : public ModuleBase,
  public Provider<Pro>,
  public Provider<>
{
public:
  TargetController();
private:
  Dep p;
};

TargetController::TargetController() :
  ModuleBase(),
  Provider<Pro>(*this, &p),
  Provider<>(*this),
  p()
{
}

int main()
{
  TargetController x;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried it with gcc and clang. Here is a link to the non working example: [link](http://ideone.com/ueJJvG).

For the `Provider<Pro>(*this, p)` the right constructor is called. But for the second example `Provider<>(*this)` the compiler tries to call the copy-constructor.

From what I understood from the [Overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) page all functions that match the expressions are should get inside the candidate function set. But either the variadic constuctor is not inside the set for the Provider without dependencies or the compiler chooses the copy-constructor in spite of beeing deleted.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Such a question makes me humble :). +1 for it

Comment: [OT]: Note that `p` is not yet construct in the call `Provider<Pro>(*this, p)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, that is right, I forgot that while reducing the code to a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that an function/method is `deleted` doesn't remove it from overload list.
And the copy constructor has higher priority over the template method (as it is not an exact match).

As workaround you may cast this to the expected type:

```
TargetController::TargetController() :
  ModuleBase(),
  Provider<Pro>(*this, p),
  Provider<>(static_cast<ModuleBase&>(*this))
{
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d9e97eb26276409)

Comment: Ok, too bad that there isn't an option to remove the copy-constructor from the overload list. Yes, this is working in my code. So, think I have to use that for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Templated constructors are never copy constructors.  When you call base's constructor and pass it a reference to base (or a derived) the copy constructor is supposed to be called.  The template isn't an option in that context.

```
Provider<>(*this)
```

Is such a context.

Worth noting that I believe VS still gets this wrong.  In that compiler you have to cast to base& or it'll call the template.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation why this is not working. Do you have a reference to the c++ standard that there is no other constructor that can be used?